# Custom Django Admin Page/View

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

Basically I'm trying to create a custom admin web page, like a custom a view.

Ideally what I want is something where like once you log in to the admin page, there would be a link somewhere like under the list of models that would redirect you to this admin center.

I have a somewhat working version currently, but I would like to have it redirect to a new URL like “ /admin/social/edit/ “ instead and not just render context into the template.

I’ve done a ton of googling and I just keep coming across things like “custom admin actions” which is not per se what I’m looking to do.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.